# How can I refresh a stored Google oAuth credential

Tags: python, google-oauth, access-token

I'm using the Python API that google provides. What I want to do is just make sure that the access token doesn't expire. I have the refresh_token stored in the credentials file. I'm just not sure how to 'check' that the token is still good before making the call to the API and if need be refreshing it and re-storing it in the credentials file.

I did a test that even if I delete the access tokens from the credentials file that it rewrites them into it using the refresh token. I'm hoping that will work for expired access tokens as well.

Thanks

```py
storage = Storage('cred_storage.txt')

credentials = storage.get()

if not credentials:
    flow = OAuth2WebServerFlow(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, OAUTH_SCOPE, REDIRECT_URI)
    authorize_url = flow.step1_get_authorize_url()
    print 'Go to the following link in your browser: ' + authorize_url
    code = raw_input('Enter verification code: ').strip()
    credentials = flow.step2_exchange(code)
    storage.put(credentials)


http = httplib2.Http()
http = credentials.authorize(http)
print http
service = build('admin', 'reports_v1', http=http)
print service
data_query = service.customerUsageReports().get(**{'date':'2015-01-07'})
feed = data_query.execute()
print feed
```

Comment: refresh_tokens don't expire really.  If you don't use it for 6 months it will expire if you request 26 different refresh_tokens from a user the first one will expire.   Assuming you are using the client library everything should be handed for you.  Access tokens expire after 60 minutes.  Wait 60 minutes and test if you get a new one

Comment: I wrote a Rails app where I tried to do what you are asking, a Just-In-Time refresh of the access token. The code was horrible, and I could not refactor it without breaking it. Finally, I just hooked up a very simple cronjob that refreshed the access token every hour no matter what, no checking, nothing. Worked like a charm. Think about it if the conditional refresh doesn't work for you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simply check the case of expired access token and refresh your expired access token like this:

```
if credentials.access_token_expired:
    credentials.refresh(httplib2.Http())
```

Tip: While developing this, you can test by editing the access token expiry date in the credentials text file and forcing it to be older than an hour

Also, in your code on the line where you are checking `if not credentials:`, you can better handle that case with:

```
if credentials is None or credentials.invalid:
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I noticed that just by keeping the refresh key in the file that it seems to update the access token automatically just on the "GET" to the credentials file. Pretty cool.

Comment: That doesn't work for me for Google Picasa. It always returns False even if acess_token has expired.

Answer (score 6):

I came across this question while trying to find a way to refresh an access token when construction a credentials object when using  `from_authorized_user_info`. Unfortunately, the following code did not work for me:

```
credentials.refresh(httplib2.Http())
```

But I found this [documentation](https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/google.auth.transport.requests.html) from the Oauth library that works wonder. Shared below:

```
import google.auth.transport.requests
import requests

request = google.auth.transport.requests.Request()
credentials.refresh(request)
```